# Entity Framework: Duplicated Key on CreateAsync (Idendity method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm having a duplicated key problem to insert my data in the database. The problem occurs because the implementation of the Seed method I insert some default values.

After that the register I create a user who has complex relationship, follows the code:

**Seed()**:

```
//Counties
context.Countie.AddOrUpdate(
    c =>  c.NameId ,
    new County { NameId = "Antrim" },
    new County { NameId = "Armagh" },
    new County { NameId = "Carlow" },
    new County { NameId = "Cavan" },
    new County { NameId = "Clare" },
    new County { NameId = "Cork" },
    new County { NameId = "Derry" },
    new County { NameId = "Donegal" },
    new County { NameId = "Down" },
    new County { NameId = "Dublin" },
```

**Register**:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email,
            BornDate = model.BornDate,
            Name = model.Name,
            Gender = model.Gender,
            Price = model.Price,
            UserType = model.UserType,
            PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber
        };
        if (model.Photo != null && model.Photo.ContentLength > 0)
            user.PhotoPath = $"\\Content\\UsersPhotos\\{FileUploaderHelper.Upload(model.Photo, model.UserType, user.Id)}";

        user.Address = new Address
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            StreetAddress = model.StreetAddress,
            PostalCode = model.PostalCode,
            Number = model.StreetNumber
        };
            user.Address.City = new City
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Name = model.City,
            County = new County { NameId = model.CountyId }
        };
            var geocoded = GeocodeHelper.GetGeoCodedAddress(user.Address);
        user.Address.Latitude = geocoded.Coordinates.Latitude.ToString().Replace(",",".");
        user.Address.Longitude = geocoded.Coordinates.Longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".");

        try
        {
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); //error occurs here
```

I believe the error is because I am instantiating a new object. But what is the correct way to do?

The following relationship follows:

Address -> City -> County

It can read:
Every address has a city which in turn has a County.

[image]

Comment: Get a `Country` from the database and assign it to `City` or attach the `new County` to the context before assigning it.

Comment: Can you post the code for this? if so, I mark as answer if it works right.

but would not give the same duplicity error? I would be entering a county that already exists in the database.

Comment: No, EF will see the object as `Unchanged` and therefore not insert it. No time for an "official" answer now. Someone else?

Comment: @GertArnold I am implementing it without problems for the explanation ... Implement step and the feedback then. If you can insert the code is easier to understand what the order process.

Comment: @GertArnold i have the same error... so I selected in the form sought in the bank one count of the same name (as the name is my key) insert in City.County and when saved from the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

Country county = db.Countie.FirstOrDefault(c => c.NameId == model.CountyId);

if(county == null)
{
     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid County");
}
else
{
    user.Address.City.County = county;
}
```

Get the county record from the context and use it instead of creating a new one.

Update:

If you have your implementation of UserManager like this then you can simply override its behavior.

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
 {
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return base.CreateAsync(user, password);
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

And make sure you are using your ApplicationManager. In your Startup add this:

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
 {
        // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
```

Comment: Same error! I think the solution is to find a way to do an override in CreateAsync and change the entity state.But I do not know how to do.

Comment: If updating the entity state is what you want then do this db.Entry(myObject).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
where myObject is the existing record in the database you want to update

Comment: I know how it works, but CreateAsync I use is Identity method and I do not know how to change.

Comment: simply give an override and not changing anything will not modify the error. Right?

Comment: Duplicate keys occur as you said, on what entity? ApplicationUser?

Comment: County. if you read, you say that I insert the counties in the seed (Seed runs when the command to create the database), it leaves these values entered to me by default.

Comment: Have you checked the database if a new record has been added to County after applying my first suggested answer? Please check the DB

Comment: I tested this solution in Web Api 2 and didn't have any problems. Simply search for the county record on the db and assign it to the user. No modifications to CreateAsync is needed. You can get the instance of the db using var db = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>();